# Permssion for View Set not working (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have custom permission for `Profile` View Set:

```
class PermissionsForProfile(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        else:
            return obj.user == request.user
```

Profile view set:

```
{
    "url": "https://.../api/v1/profiles/2/",
    "user": "https://.../api/v1/users/2/",
    "gender": null,
    "status": null,
    "birthday": null,
    "city": null,
    "about": null,
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Test",
    "image": "https://.../images/users/2/test.jpg",
    "points": 0,
    "profile_type": 1
}
```

I logged in from the user with `ID = 2` (`"user"` field equal user's URL) and I can not do `PUT` request. Looks like this user is not an owner of this object.

How to fix it?

**UPD:**

Profile ViewSet -

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (PermissionsForProfile, )
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Comment: Can you add the view code?, also the model to have a more complete context.

Comment: @cabesuon , I did update the answer

Comment: It look OK .. Can you add the error message? .. Add a `print` statement in `has_object_permission` function that shows `request.user.id` and `obj.user.id`, and add the result to be sure of the comparison

Comment: @cabesuon , hello! Print method shows correctly obj.user.id and request.user.id. But I can not PUT, POST request.